# Execute a Javascript function from a button in a table row cell which was generated by PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, button, html-table, row

I want to call a Javascript function from a table row cell.
I need to pass the id of that row as well.

In one cell I use an href (which does popup my edit dialog), but does not pass the Id (BrId).
The next one, well ideally a button which invokes a Javascript function (though I've seen code/functions which associates a click event function within `$(document).ready(function() {.....etc}`) but unsure if this will pick up the required Id (BrId) which is a primary key to a database table.

Code is:

```
foreach ($myrows as $row) {               
       echo "<tr>"; 

         echo '<td style="border:none;">' .$row->BrId. '</td>'; 
         echo '......'
         echo '......'
         echo '<td style="border:none;"><a href="#dialog" name="modal">Edit this branch </td>';
         echo '<td style="border:none;"><button onclick="EditBranch (1)"></td>';
 }
```

Ideally the function would also show my popup div ( id= dialog ) as the `"a href="#dialog" name="modal"` does.

If this helps, here's a section of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     //select all the a tags with name equal to modal
     $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {

     //Cancel the link behavior
     e.preventDefault();

     //Get the A tag 
     var id = $(this).attr('href');  //gets me my div id

    //other code for transition effects and positioning of my div....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the row id through a custom html data attribute :

```
echo '<a href="#dialog" name="modal" data-id="' . $row->BrId . '"> Edit this branch </a>';
```

Then, you simply retrieve it like that :

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```